# Adding a tooltip to an image

Tags: python, gtk, tooltip, pygtk

I'm trying to add a tooltip to an image.  Following a [PyGTK tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TooltipsObject.html) it seems that this should work:

```
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file(image_path)
box.pack_start(image, expand=False)

tooltip = gtk.Tooltips()
tooltip.set_tip(image, "Hello!")
```

Except it doesn't.  Nothing happens when I mouse over the image.  However, I know that works with buttons (I ran the sample code from the tutorial).

With GTK 2.12 and above, I could probably just use `image.set_tooltip_text("Hello!")` but I'm stuck at 2.10.4 and have to use `gtk.Tooltips`.

**Edit**

According to the [documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktooltips.html) for `gtk.Tooltips`:

> Tooltips can only be set on widgets which have their own X window. To check if a widget has its own window use `widget.flags()&gtk.NO_WINDOW`. To add a tooltip to a widget that doesn't have its own window, place the widget inside a gtk.EventBox and add a tooltip to the eventbox instead.

So that solves my problem but leaves me a bit confused.  I checked the flags for a button and it has the same `gtk.NO_WINDOW` flag that images have.  So why don't buttons need an EventBox but images do?

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy its interface, GktButton creates an event box (well, something like an event box) for itself, internally.  I.e. it captures events in a non-visible gdk window.  GtkImage doesn't have a similar interface to satisfy so it doesn't need to capture events.

Perhaps it's an accident of the button's internal implementation that using the tooltip interface works without embedding a button in an EventBox or perhaps the tooltip interface **actually** depends upon a gdk window whether it's visible or not and the Widget interface lacks that sort of flag.